# $\bmod p\!:\ x^2\equiv 1\iff x\equiv \pm1\ $ for prime $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime. Show that for all integers $x$, $x^2\equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ p) $ if and only if $x \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ p)$ or $ x \equiv p-1 \ (\text{mod} \ p ). $

---

I know that I have to prove this both forward and backward. I'm not really sure where to begin

Comment: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Answer (score 3):

The direction $(\Leftarrow)$ is clear. For $(\Rightarrow),\,$ if $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$, we have $$x^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \!\!\!\pmod p \iff (x - 1)(x + 1) \equiv 0 \!\!\!\pmod p \iff p\mid (x - 1)(x + 1)$$
By [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216213/242), since $p$ is prime, $p$ divides the product iff it divides one of the terms, and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

The proof in T. Bongers answer is perhaps the most direct way to proceed. A slightly more general viewpoint lends further insight, since it relates to our prior intuition about the number of roots a polynomial may have. Recall that if $x=1$ is a root of a polynomial $f(x)$ then, by the Factor Theorem, we infer: $\ f(x) = (x-1) g(x)$. Now suppose that $x = r \ne 1$ is a different root. Now eval'ing at $\,x\!=\!r\,$  $\Rightarrow f(r) = (r-1) g(r)\equiv 0.$ Since $r-1\not\equiv0,\,$ we know, by Bezout, that it has an inverse $s.$ Multiplying by $s$ we infer $g(r)\equiv 0.$ Hence every other root of $f$ is a root of the lower degree polynomial $g$. Thus if $f$ is quadratic then the only other root of $f$ is the root of the linear polynomial $g$. In particular, a quadratic has at most two roots.

By induction on the degree of $f$ the same proof shows that a nonzero polynomial has no more roots than its degree. Note that the only property of the integers mod $p$ that we employed is that nonzero elements are cancellable. Thus the proof will work in any "number system" that has this property, i.e. any [integral domain.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) In fact, it is easy to show that this property characterizes integral domains, i.e. every nonzero polynomial has no more roots than its degree $\iff$ every nonzero element is cancellable.