# Elementary proof of $\gcd(a, b) = 1 \wedge a\ |\ b\ c \Rightarrow a \ | \ c $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

How does on prove $\gcd(a, b) = 1 \wedge a\  |\  b\ c \Rightarrow a \ | \ c $ with as elementary steps as possible (i.e. not using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique prime factorization))?

EDIT:  I saw that this theorem is called *Gauss Theorem* and is proved formally for integers $\mathbb Z$ in Coq, https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.ZArith.Znumtheory.html#Gauss

EDIT: Clarification:  I forgot to tell that I want to prove this for the natural numbers $\mathbb N \geq 0$.  Is Bezout's lemma applicable for the natural numbers, or is some other method needed?

Comment: Yes it seem to be a dupe. Sorry about that.

Comment: For a *very*  elementary proof (only euclidean division), not mentioned in the above link, you can take a look at my [answer to a similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218430/simple-proof-that-if-a2-is-divisible-by-a-prime-b-then-a-is-divisible-by/1218573#1218573).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!  I was hoping for a constructive proof - just saying that there exists a smallest element in the set with the desired properties is a bit messy (I'm trying to do a formal proof), but is doable I'm sure.

Comment: The proof I gave (I think it's Cauchy's) relies precisely on the fact that $\mathbf N$ is well ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Bezout's theorem is allowed or not.
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then by Bezouts's theorem there exist $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ma+nb=1$. It follows that $mac+nbc=c$. Therefore since $a$ divides $mac$ and $nbc$ it must divide $c=mac+nbc$.

Comment: Actually I needed something more trivial (or a trivial proof of Bezouts' theorem).  Just using "obvious" properties of gcd and divisibility...

Comment: Is my proof here trivial enough: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533795/bezouts-theorem/1533855#1533855

Comment: Thanks! (see my comment above about a constructive proof...)

Comment: A clarification: I'd like to do the proof for the natural numbers $0,1,2,...$. I don't think Bezout's lemma holds for the natural numbers, since one of the coefficients usually is negative.  Or am I mistaken?