# Smallest positive element of $ \{ax + by: x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is $\gcd(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $S = \{ax + by: x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$  and let $e > 0$ be the smallest element in $S$. Prove that $e \mid a$, and hence prove that $e = \gcd(a,b)$

I'm afraid I can't provide much of my initial working here because I'm at a loss of how to start.

I suppose that to show $e\mid a$ I would have to show that $eg = a$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}$. But I have no idea how I would do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I first saw this problem, I was pretty surprised at how the proof went, so I'll just get you started on it.

By the Division Theorem, we have:
$$a=qe+r \text{ for } 0 \leq r < e$$
Now, we need to show $r=0$. To do this, we can use the fact that $e=ax+by$ for some $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$ and that $a=1a+0b$, so:
$$1a+0b=q(ax+by)+r \implies a(1-qx)-bqy=r$$
Now we can combine the fact that $r=au+bv$ for $u,v \in \Bbb{Z}$ and that $0 \leq r < e$ to prove $r=0$.

Comment: Wow that's really helpful, thanks! In your second to last line, should that be $a(1-q) - qby = r$? Also wondering - how do you know that $r = au + bv$?

Comment: @leanne Thanks for the typo catch! Since we have $r=a(1-q)-bqy=a(1-q)+b(-qy)$, we can set $u=1-q \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $v=-qy \in \Bbb{Z}$ so that $r=au+bv$.

Comment: @leanne Note that the proof depends only on the fact that $S$ is closed under remainders.In fact this follows from the fact that $S$ is closed under differences, and one can present the proof in a way that emphasizes this fundamental innate (group / ideal) structure - see my answer. Such algebraic structure is ubiquitous in number theory and algebra, so it is essential to bring it to the fore.

Comment: @BillDubuque "Closed under remainders" means that the Division Theorem is true for $\Bbb{Z}$ and that it is a Euclidean domain, correct? Just want to make sure.

Comment: @Noble The proof employs the Division Algorithm, and it will work in any Euclidean domain ( i.e. one enjoying such division with "smaller" remainder) to show that all ideals are principal - generated by any nonzero element of least size. In fact there is a sort of generalization to arbitrary PIDs, see the [Dedekind-Hasse criterion.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20dedekind%20hasse)

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for telling me about the Dedekind-Hasse criterion! I didn't know about that before.

Comment: @Noble Strangely, that pretty little result is not as widely known as it deserves to be. So  I try to correct that by emphasizing it whenever it seems enlightening to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *conceptual* way to prove  [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the gcd. The set $\rm\,S\,$ of integers of the form $\rm\,a x + b y,\ x,y\in \mathbb Z,\,$ is closed under subtraction so, by the Lemma below, every positive $\rm\,k\in S\,$ is divisible by $\rm\,d = $ least positive $\rm\in S.\,$  So $\rm\,a,b\in S$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\rm d\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,d\,$ is a *common* divisor of $\rm\,a,b,\,$ necessarily the  *greatest* such by $\rm\ c\mid a,b\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\mid d = ax+by$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\le d$.

**Lemma** $\ \ $ Let $\,\rm S\ne\emptyset \,$ be a set of integers $>0\,$ closed under subtraction $> 0,\,$ i.e. for all $\rm\,n,m\in S, \,$ $\rm\ n > m\ \Rightarrow\  n-m\, \in\, S.\,$  Then the least $\rm\:\ell\in S\,$ divides every element of $\,\rm S.$

**Proof** ${\bf\ 1}\,\  $ If not there is a least nonmultiple $\rm\,n\in S,\,$ contra  $\rm\,n-\ell \in S\,$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Proof** ${\bf\ 2}\,\rm\,\ \   S\,$ closed under subtraction $\rm\,\Rightarrow\,S\,$ closed under remainder (mod), when it is $\ne 0,$ since mod is simply repeated subtraction, i.e. $\rm\ a\ mod\ b\, =\, a - k b\, =\, a\!-\!b\!-\!b\!-\cdots\! -\!b.\,$ Thus $\rm\,n\in S\,$ $\Rightarrow \rm\, (n\ mod\ \ell) = 0,\,$ else it is in $\,\rm S\,$ and smaller than $\rm\,\ell,\,$ contra minimality of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Remark** $\ $ In a nutshell, two inductions yield

$\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf subtraction} $
$\Rightarrow\:\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf mod} = remainder = repeated\ subtraction $
$\Rightarrow\:\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf gcd} = repeated\ mod\ (Euclid's\ algorithm)$

Viewed *constructively* this yields the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) for the gcd.

The conceptual structure will be clarified when one studies *ideals* of rings, where the above proof generalizes to show that Euclidean domains are PIDs.

Comment: This is the most intuitive proof I have seen thus far. The standard proof of [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Proof) uses the division algorithm and is not something you would naturally think of (some authors may skip it entirely). It leads to nightmarish [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277437/proving-uniqueness-that-if-s-asbtasbt0-a-b-in-bbb-n-and-d-d-i?noredirect=1&lq=1). I did have to sit down with a piece of paper and look at some examples of positive integer sets closed under subtraction e.g. $\{2,4,6,8\}$ .

Comment: One thing I could mention, you seem to switch between two sets. To be explicit let $S = \{ ax + by : x , y \in \mathbb Z  \}$ and $S' = \{ax+by > 0 : x, y \in \mathbb Z \}$. You showed that if we define $ d = \min( S ') $ , then $ d \mid a $ and $d \mid  b $. But two issues. How do we know $a,b$ are in $S ' $, since we did not assume $a,b$ are positive. I suppose if $ a < 0 $ then $a(-1) + b(0) > 0 $ demonstrates $-a \in S ' $ for integers $ x = -1, y = 0 $. And if $d | -a $ it follows that $d | a $. But how do you show $d$ divides any element in the set $S$. Also $a,b$ must be nonzero.

Comment: @john Yes, generally if nonempty $S$ is closed under subtraction then it is also closed under negation $(s\in S\Rightarrow s-s = 0\in S\Rightarrow 0-s = -s\in S),\,$ so $\,a,b\in S\Rightarrow |a|,|b|\in S,\,$ and $a\Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z = |a|\Bbb Z + |b|\Bbb Z,\,$ so wlog we may assume $a,b\ge 0\,$ (and not both are $0).\,$ You may find of interest a [proof of Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216353/242) by this method.

Answer (score 0):

One must define $e$ as the smallest **positive** element of $S$.

Since $e\in \{ax + by: x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, there are some numbers $x_1,y_1$ such that $e = ax_1+by_1$.

Suppose some positive member $f$ of $S = \{ax + by: x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ were not a multiple of $e$.  Then we have some numbers $x_2,y_2$ such that $f = ax_2+by_2$.

Since $e$ is the smallest, we must have $e<f$.  Let $r$ be the remainder when $f$ is divided by $e$.  Then using the relations
\begin{align}
f & = ax_2 + by_2 \\
e & = ax_1 + by_1
\end{align}
you can show that $r \in S$.  But $0<r$ since $f$ is not a multiple of $e$ and $r<e$ since $r$ was a remainder upon division by $e$.

That means there is a positive member of $S$, namely $r$ that is smaller than $e$.  That can't happen since $e$ is the smallest.

Hence every member of $S$ is a multiple of $e$.  Therefore $e$ is a common divisor of $a\in S$ and $b\in S$.

Comment: You showed that every positive $k \in S$ is a multiple of $e $ where $e$ stands for the least positive element in $S $. Then how do you go from there to show every member of $S$ is a multiple of $e$? Specifically how do you show that $e$ is a common divisor of $a \in S$ or $b\in S$, since $a,b$ may not even be positive.