# Proving that smallest period divides every other period

Tags: elementary-number-theory, periodic-functions

This question was left as homework by my instructor and he didn't discussed it.

> An arithmetical function f is called periodic mod k if k>0 and f(m) =f(n) whenever m$\equiv$ n (mod k). The integer k is called a period of f.

(i) If f is periodic mod k, prove that f has a smallest positive period $k_{0}$ and $k_{0}$ |k.

Attempt : by well ordering principle there exists a smallest period $k_{0}$ .

Now, m$\equiv$ n (mod k) => f(m) =f(n) => m$\equiv$ n (mod $k_{0}$ => m-n = $k_{0}$ x,$ m-n =k_{1} y$ , which implies $k_{0} x = k_{1} y$ and $k_0 < k_{1}$  implies that x>y , but I am still not getting that y divides x to prove what is asked.

Can you please help in deducing that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could perhaps try a proof by contradiction.  Assume that $k_0 \nmid k_1$.  Then there are integers $q,r$ with $0 < r < k_0$ such that $k_1 = qk_0 + r$.

Given any positive integer $x$, there are integers $q',r'$ with $0 \leq r' < r$ such that $x = q'r + r'$.  Therefore
$$
f(x) = f(q'r + r') = f(q'(k_1-qk_0) + r') = f(q'k_1 - q'qk_0 + r').
$$
Since both $k_0$ and $k_1$ are periods of $f$, $f(q'k_1 - q'qk_0 + r') = f(r')$.  Thus for any positive integer $x$, $f(x) = f(r')$, where $x \equiv r'~(mod~r)$.  This means that $r$ is a period of $f$ that is smaller than $k_0$, contradicting the choice of $k_0$.

Comment: This is essentially a special case of the 2nd proof of the basic Lemma linked in my answer. It's best to *encapsulate* these basic properties in Lemmas, Theorems etc for convenient reuse, not to repeat their proofs inline every time we need to invoke them - that's what *abstraction* is all about (in the language of abstract algebra it bolls down to Euclidean domains are PIDs, but one doesn't need to know that to understand the very simple linked proofs - including a one line proof).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the periods set $P$ is nonempty & closed under subtraction $>0\,$ $(k>\bar k\in P\Rightarrow k\!-\!\bar k\in P),\,$ so  the least period divides every period by a [fundamental Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216353/242) (which has a one-line proof).